# A question regarding Android File I/O API?

Tags: android, file, io

I need to write multiple blocks of the following chunk into a file

```
+----------+--------------+---------------------+
| FileName | Size of File | Binary Dump Of File |
+----------+--------------+---------------------+
```

There are two variants of file writers I could see. 
1. FileWriter - allows writing [string,char[],one byte]
2. BufferFileoutputStream - allows writing [byte array]

I need an File object that can write String,Integer and binary data. But I could not find any direct way out. We can definitely have work-arounds, like converting Strings and Integers to byte array. But is there a better alternative ??

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is an alternative. It is called: **java.io.DataOutputStream**. To know if it is helpful to your problem we would need more informations.